# Menú principiande en Java

Tags: java, bucles

Soy nuevo en java y acabo de empezar a hacer condicionales y algo de bucles.

Tengo este problema: quiero hacer un Do-While para que me vuelva al menú principal si no marcan la opción de salir, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Os dejo aquí el programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        //do {
        int entrada;
        System.out.println("-------------------MENÚ-------------------");
        System.out.println("[1] Día de la semana");
        System.out.println("[2] Números aleatorios");
        System.out.println("[3] Contraseña");
        System.out.println("[0] Salir del menú.");

        entrada = teclado.nextInt();
        switch (entrada) {
            case 1:
                String dia;  // tengo que poner dos string, porque sino no me deja escribir cuando pido el día. Tampoco sé por qué. Asique el resto de cosas que hay que introducir lo he hecho con JOptionPane.
                String diaSemana;
                System.out.println("Por favor introduzca un día de la semana para saber si es laboral o festivo");
                dia = teclado.nextLine();
                diaSemana = teclado.nextLine(); 
                switch (diaSemana) {
                    case "lunes":
                    case "martes":
                    case "miercoles":
                    case "jueves":
                    case "viernes":
                    System.out.println("Es día laboral");
                break;
                    case "sabado":

                    case "domingo":
                    System.out.println("Es festivo!!!");
                }   
                break;
            case 2: 

                int num;
                int num1;
                System.out.println("Por favor introduzca un número positivo");
                num = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Por favor escoja otro número");
                num1 = teclado.nextInt();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {

                int aleatorio = (int)( Math.random() * (num - num1)+num1);
                System.out.println(aleatorio);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                String password = "tontoelquelolea";
                String pass = "";

                    for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
                    pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor introduzca la contraseña. Tiene 3 intentos");
                    System.out.println(password.equalsIgnoreCase(pass));        
                }   
            break;
            case 0: 
                String salir = "si";
                String out = "";
                out = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Desa salir del menu?");
                if(out != salir) {

                }else {

                    System.out.println("Hasta la próxima");
                }
            break;
            default:


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola igual esta es la primera vez que utilizo esta página para responder a alguna duda de alguien. Espero te sirva este programa, lo he probado y creo que te irá bien.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class borrar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(entrada);
            String op = "";
            do {
                System.out.println ("*************************************");
                System.out.println ("***** Elija una de las opciones *****");
                System.out.println ("*****   1. Primer opción        *****");
                System.out.println ("*****   2. Segunda opción       *****");
                System.out.println ("*****   3. Tercer opción        *****");
                System.out.println ("*****   4. Salir                *****");
                System.out.println ("*************************************");
                System.out.print ("Elije la opción: ");
                try {
                    op = buffer.readLine();
                    System.out.print("--- La opción elegida es: ");
                    switch(Integer.parseInt(op)) {
                        case 1: System.out.println("Opción 1 ---");
                                        break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("Opción 2 ---");
                                        break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("Opción 3 ---");
                                        break;
                        case 4: System.out.println("Salir ---");
                                        break;
                        default : break;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println (e.toString());
                }
            } while (!op.equals("4"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu programa se repita debes usar las condiciones Do-While, como bien has dicho.
El funcionamiento de estas condiciones funciona del siguiente modo, dentro del Do se coloca todo lo que deseas repetir, al terminar debes colocar while y entre parentesis una condición, mientras la condición del interior del paréntesis no se cumpla repíteme el bucle

Un ejemplo sería:

```
Do{
//preguntas un numero
//Escribe un texto
}
while(numero!=7); //mientras ese numero no sea 7 repite el texto.
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que hacemos ahora es lo siguiente:

1 - Pintamos las instrucciones al usuario.
2 - Introduce el código (0-1-2-3)
3 - El código ejecuta la lógica del `switch case`.
4 - Pintamos las instrucciones al usuario.
5 - Vuelve al inicio del `while`

Hará todo este bucle hasta que el usuario introduzca algo diferente a 1-2-3.

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        int entrada;
        //Llamamos a un metodo que solo pinta en pantalla.
        pintarTextoInformativo();

        entrada = teclado.nextInt();
        while(entrada>0 && entrada <= 3){

            /**
            *
            * Todo tu lógica va aquí podrías extraerlo todo a métodos
            * como el "pintarTextoInformativo" pero primero haz lo sencillo y 
            * ya lo harás mejor mas adelante
            *
            */

            pintarTextoInformativo();
            entrada = teclado.nextInt();
        }
    }
    //Creamos este metodo, para que sea mas comodo la lectura del código.
    public static void pintarTextoInformativo(){
        System.out.println("-------------------MENÚ-------------------");
        System.out.println("[1] Día de la semana");
        System.out.println("[2] Números aleatorios");
        System.out.println("[3] Contraseña");
        System.out.println("[0] Salir del menú.");
    }
}
```